# Fixed navigation won't center on android broswer

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, iphone, mobile

I've added a fixed navigation bar to my website using the jquery.sticky.js and it works perfectly on my iPhone and desktop. However, on android (2.2 I believe) the navigation floats to the left and the clickable area for each link appears to be wrong. I tried adding jQuery to only load the jquery.sticky.js if the browser ISN'T android, but to no avail.
I tried this (i'm a beginner when it comes to programming and found this code but modified it slightly) but it doesn't work!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
 var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1; //&& ua.indexOf("mobile");
if(isAndroid != isAndroid) {
 (function(){
$("#navigation").sticky({topSpacing:0});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will always evaluate to false:

```
if (isAndroid != isAndroid)
```

meaning that the if block is never executed.